# What is the best looking desktop application UI that you have seen?

Tags: user-interface, desktop-application

I'm designing a new desktop app and would like to get a feel for what good designs you have seen out there.

Comment: As it stands, this is a ridiculous question. Not all well-designed applications look exactly the same. You have to tailor your interface to your application's specific *functionality* first, and then tweak the UI design. Without more information about the app you're designing, no one can give you a good answer. But the golden rule is: When in doubt, follow the conventions of your platform and/or the most well-known and commonly used applications in your field.

Comment: I wanted to make this a community wiki just to have people's suggestions on what their favorite UIs they have used are but have no idea how to do that.  I have seen a similar question posed as a community wiki for web apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295970/what-in-your-opinion-is-the-best-looking-webapp

Comment: There used to be a similar question but that's old and off-topic enough to have been deleted from the site :/

Comment: @digiarnie: Beyond my last comment about this being *highly* dependent on your specific application's functionality and target OS, that type of question is off-topic now. Some of the older questions from the early days are still around (like the one you found), while others have already been deleted. There's been a bit of a change as to what's considered on topic. See these two blog posts: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Comment: That being said, I'd personally vote to reopen if you edited the question to be specifically about your application, and provided us with some more details. I think that question qualifies as "answerable". But I don't know how the community feels, and I can't speak for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I think I'm happy to leave it closed as I don't necessarily want specific ideas.  I just wanted to get an idea of what various good desktop designs looked like just to be inspired or get some new ideas.  Personally I like hearing from others about what they think is good or bad but if it doesn't fit with the rules then lets just leave it closed :)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the apps made by Sofa:

http://www.madebysofa.com/#software